# authenticate silverlight app from third party software

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, silverlight-3.0

> I need your help. I have a requirement to perform secure log in for my silverlight application(using wcf). I am launching this app from old call center software. From here, I need to pass some information to silverlight app in a secured manner (currently passing as url parameters). I doesn't want to provide log in screen again, because the user is already authenticated by call center s/w.

Please provide me your valuble suggestions.

Thanks in advance,
Raghavendra K.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways for passing data between applications in Web. You mentioned one of them: query string. There are others, such as Cookies and POST data.

Comment: Boris, thanks for your suggestion. I am not able to POST data from my call center application. It is just like windows based application. It was a old s/w.

Comment: Sorry, I saw your comment just now. Is it still relevant? Have you already found a solution? What it is?